# How can I call a command using the following output?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Please see the following command I'm running to obtain the GUID of a particular application. It works as expected as you can see from the screenshot underneath.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
    Get-ItemProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match "Dell SupportAssist" } |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString
```

[image]

What I'd like to do is call the uninstall command from the output GUID. So something like:

```
MsiExec.exe /X{OUTPUT}
```

or for this example

```
MsiExec.exe /X{95BD6E30-2B18-4FB0-B5AE-8250E5584831}
```

Can this be done?

I don't want to use a huge VBS script that I can't read that you found online, I'd like to understand it bit by bit ;)
I don't want to use `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product` - See https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, could you expand on that at all? Or is that simply added to the above command?

Comment: Just add that command to your Powershell script at the end. The & will execute the string that follows it, in this case your uninstall string.

Comment: @Scepticalist Unfortunately not. It'll only work that way if the string contains just the executable, not if it also contains parameters. I posted an answer with a working solution and will delete my sloppy comment shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys my colleague found this on another Stackoverflow post:

```
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | select UninstallString
$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | select UninstallString
if ($uninstall64) {
    $uninstall64 = $uninstall64.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
    $uninstall64 = $uninstall64.Trim()
    Write "Uninstalling..."
    start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall64 /quiet" -Wait
}
if ($uninstall32) {
    $uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
    $uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
    Write "Uninstalling..."
    start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /quiet" -Wait
}
```

This works perfectly and includes switches for silent uninstall - It doesn't seem to use `Win32_Product`.

Any reason why this wouldn't be appropriate rolling out en masse compared to the suggestions above?

Answer (score 0):

You may try as @Ansgar mentioned something like:

Code edited with example for Dell Power*:

```
$DellSoftware = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
    Get-ItemProperty |
    Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "dell power*" } |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString

$DellSoftware.UninstallString -match '(?<MSI>\w+.exe) (?<Args>\S+)'
Start-Process -FilePath $Matches.MSI -ArgumentList $Matches.Args
```

If you check the `$Matches` variable it should contain:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                  
Args                           /X{18469ED8-8C36-4CF7-BD43-0FC9B1931AF8}                                                                                                                                               
MSI                            MsiExec.exe                                                                                                                                                                            
0                              MsiExec.exe /X{18469ED8-8C36-4CF7-BD43-0FC9B1931AF8}
```

It returns a hash table with the grouped matches. This is why I am being able to separate the executable into the MSI key and the arguments into the args key. Then starting the process calling the executable as a FilePath param and providing the args for the ArgumentList param.

Then the result:

[image]

What is happeinig here is that the property UninstallString, returns, as you may guess - String. You need to tell to the PowerShell to treat this string as an expression. 
To do so you need to use the `&` symbol in front, putting the statement, that you would like to execute in round brackets. 
Same behaviour could be observed, when you try to launch a file from a location that contains white space. Because of it, powershell puts it in brackets, and to be able to execute it, puts the `&` in front - i.e. `& 'C:\Program Files\'`

Hope that clarifies the case :)

Comment: I just thought of another example: `'get-process' will return a string, but if you would like to execute the string, you may use `& 'get-process'`.

Comment: Unfortunately my comment was too sloppy. Just using the call operator will only work when the command string contains nothing but the executable. Since in this case the command string also contains parameters PowerShell would look for an executable `"msiexec.exe /x{...}"`, which does not exist, and would thus throw an error.

Comment: The term 'MsiExec.exe /X{95BD6E30-2B18-4FB0-B5AE-8250E5584831}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  From what you've put. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ansgar: True story and good point! Still, there is a workaround, if using regular expressions: 

    `$DellSoftware.UninstallString -match '(?<MSI>\w+.exe) (?<Args>\S+)'`

    `Start-Process -FilePath $Matches.MSI -ArgumentList $Matches.Args`


Note, those are two lines, but I am having troubles separating in the comment section!
It's a bit overcomplicated, but it works.

Comment: I'm still getting an error using that.  So the main issue with that command Ivan is that I'm getting The term 'MsiExec.exe /X{95BD6E30-2B18-4FB0-B5AE-8250E5584831}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.  This feels the closest I've got and it's like I need a further command to tell powershell to open the UninstallString command in CMD.EXE instead perhaps?

Comment: I wili edit my answer above, with an example working on my PC

Comment: YES! Thank you Ivan that does work! And thank you for explaining it, I still think I need to take my time to break it down and work it out fully but works just fine in the immediate so thank you! 

Could we take it one step further though and add some switches/flags like /qn /f etc? Would you put that somewhere in the argument?

Comment: No worries, as `$Matches.Args` is a string, you just need to concatinate using `+` sign. For example: `$Matches.Args + ' /qc'`. 
Or in the code use: `Start-Process -FilePath $Matches.MSI -ArgumentList ($Matches.Args + ' /qc')`.
Note: You need to put white space in the single quote, in order to separate the switches, otherwise it would be "glued" to the previous string.

Comment: If you would like to learn something more about Regular Expressions in powershell, use: `Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions -showwindow` or: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6

Comment: About PowerShell parsing: `Get-Help about_Parsing -ShowWindow` or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-6

Comment: Ivan, again thank you so much! I will have a look at the Get-Help commands for sure and probably a course or two ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your registry query returns a custom object with the uninstall command string as one of its properties. To invoke that command string you can create a scriptblock from that string and then invoke that scriptblock (e.g. via the call operator). Pipe the output of your PowerShell statements into a `ForEach-Object` loop like this:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    & ([Scriptblock]::Create($_.UninstallString))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really helpful for my own development and no doubt others

For some reason it opens the menu that describes the switches/flags you can use (like /qn /f etc) rather than run the uninstaller - Did you go wrong somewhere?

Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString | ForEach-Object {& ([Scriptblock]::Create($_.UninstallString))}

Comment: That should work AFAICS. Try just displaying the created scriptblock (remove the call operator and the loop will output the scriptblock content in string form).

Comment: Sorry Ansgar I'm a bit of a noob in comparison on Powershell and I'm not quite grasping what you want me to try.

Comment: Just do `... | ForEach-Object {[Scriptblock]::Create($_.UninstallString)}` instead of the current `ForEach-Object` at the end of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an msi, it's very easy with the package commands:

```
get-package *dell* | Uninstall-Package -whatif
```

EDIT:

If you want the exact command... (-force in case it asks to install nuget)

```
Uninstall-Package 'Dell SupportAssist' -Force
```

Comment: That would be a bit heavy handed if you have other Dell products you want to keep installed - If it works, not trying that though :)

Comment: It's safe to try with the -whatif.  You can specify the full name if you want.